# Extracting an Integer from a String in Order to Convert to an Int

Tags: sql-server, casting

I'm looking for help on writing the script that will extract the number after the "-" from the string so that I can convert just that number into an integer in SQL Server.

I have varchar columns as follows:

```
reference_id |reference
R6165522     |R6165522-1
B4587998     |B4587998-20
```

I've tried the script below, but I get a conversion error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'R6165522-1' to data type int.

It seems like `right` should be added somewhere in order to get the for right character.

```
SELECT reference 
FROM this_table 
WHERE reference_id = 'R6165522'
ORDER BY 1, CAST(replace([reference], '-', '') AS int);
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: That I can produce another column without a name that contains only the character(s) after the dash in the original value. For ex., 
reference_id | reference
R6165522  | 1
B4587998  | 20

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
SELECT reference 
FROM this_table 
WHERE reference_id = 'R6165522'
ORDER BY cast(SUBSTRING([reference],CHARINDEX('-',[reference]) + 1,LEN([reference])) as int);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `reference` always consists of `reference_id` + `'-'` + a number then you can replace the starting part:

```
SELECT reference 
FROM this_table 
WHERE reference_id = 'R6165522'
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(reference, reference_id + '-', '') AS int);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33fbc6d25a1f32a25a396cb76a27ae43).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you technically want to *replace* anything before the `-`, the function you are looking for is `STUFF`:

```
SELECT [reference]
FROM this_table 
WHERE reference_id = 'R6165522'
ORDER BY CAST(STUFF([reference], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [reference]), '') AS int);
```